# Finite dimensional subspace is weak star closed

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show the weak star closed convex hull of a finite set of points is contained in the linear span of those points.

It's enough to show that any finite dimensional subspace $V$ of a Banach space $Z$ is weak star closed in $Z$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, it is a closed subspace of $Z$ in the norm topology. How can I show that it is also weak star closed? Also, it this result true for arbitrary subspaces?

Comment: Is $Z$ given as the dual space of another Banach space?  Otherwise what do you mean by weak star?

Comment: Yes, if $Z=X^*$ for some Banach space $X$

Answer (score 4):

All finite dimensional subspaces of Hausdorff topological vector spaces are closed. This is theorem 1.21 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

This is true not only for arbitrary subspaces of Banach spaces, but in fact for arbitrary subspaces of locally convex spaces. For any locally convex space $X$, the weak and original closures of any convex set $E \subset X$ are the same (see, for instance, Theorem 3.12 [here](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/functional-analysis-_-rudin-2th.pdf)). Since Banach spaces are locally convex and subspaces of any space are convex, this shows that the weak and original closures of any subspace of a Banach space are the same.

Comment: If the OP meant weak-* (presumably relative to a Banach space $X$ such that $Z = X^*$), this is not relevant.